How to extract duplicate values from local variable in Appian?
I have this criteria map data and inside of the object are multiple criteriaResults. Two of the criteriaResults have the same criteriaCode: C020. How do I remove one and leave the other?
local!combinedCriteriaResults: a!flatten(
    {
      local!cumulativeCDE31Results.criteriaResults,
      local!filteredCumulativeCDE4Results.criteriaResults,
      local!cumulativeCDE5Results.criteriaResults,
      local!cumulativeCDE6Results.criteriaResults
    }
  ),


